# JQuery Animation not working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a website with a sidebar with settings and such, and I want the sidebar to slide out and the content should just resize. I am trying to make it look like a clean animation. Although when I try it, the content just slides down below the sidebar. I have no idea why. Here is my code.

**Links**

```
    <!-- Latest Bootstrap V4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome V4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- JQuery V2.1.4 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap V4 Javascript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row all">
    <div id="infobox" class="col-md-4">
        test
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="col-md-8">
        <nav id="bar">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" id="info" title="Info"></i><div id="title" class="text-center">test</div>
        </nav>
        <div id="chat">
            t
        </div>
        <div id="input">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Enter chat here">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="send">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-effects-wrapper{
    float: right;
}

#text, #send{
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: left;
}
#text{
    width: 90%
}
#send{
    width: 10%;
}

#bar{
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #373a3c;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: inline;
}
#bar #title{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    padding-top: .25rem;
    padding-bottom: .25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-right: 45%;
}

#chat{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 87%;
}

#input{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    // min-height: 5%;
}

#content{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    /*width: auto;*/
}

#infobox{
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    /*position: relative;*/
    height: 100%;
}
.all{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#send").click(function () {
        alert("test");
        $("#chat").html(document.getElementById("text").value);
        document.getElementById("text").value = "";
        return false;
    });
    $("#info").click(function () {
        if($("#infobox").is(":visible")){
        $("#infobox").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
        $("#content").animate({
            width: "100%",
            float: "left"
        }, 1000, "", function () {
//            alert("all done");
        });
    }else{
        $("#content").animate({
            width: "66.666667%",
            float: "left"
        }, 1000, "", function () {
//            alert("all done");
        });
        $("#infobox").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);

    }
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/zivuzipoju/

Comment: Is there a reason not to build off of Bootstrap's Off-Canvas demo? http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Comment: @Stef That is obviously an experimental feature, although when it gets finished it might help me. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: I'd say in this case it's no more experimental than the solution you're working on. But I'll tinker with your JS Bin and see what we can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rudy Setiady I was able to have an idea of what to do, then I was stumped because for some odd reason there was some sort of padding or something that chrome was not able to find. So I just set the initial width to 150% so that it looked like it was full screen. Then when the sidebar came out, I would set it to 100%. When I did this, of course there would be a scrollbar. So to fix that, I just set `overflow: hidden` on body.